# VSTS build issues with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a Xamarin.Android project which references a Core PCL (Profile111).  Core PCL references Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLLiteStore (see below):

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.3.1.0\lib\portable-win+net45+wp8+wpa81+monotouch+monoandroid\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLiteStore, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore.3.1.0\lib\portable-win+net45+wp8+wpa81+monotouch10+monoandroid10+xamarinios10\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLiteStore.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```

Other than these (added as NuGet packages, I am referencing ReactiveUI and Microsoft.Bcl.  See packages.config for a complete list of referenced packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="reactiveui" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="reactiveui-core" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Rx-Core" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Rx-Interfaces" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Rx-Linq" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Rx-Main" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Rx-PlatformServices" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Splat" version="1.4.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.core" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
</packages>
```

I am getting compile issues in VSTS but not locally on my box.  On my box, I can compile fine in both Debug or Release config.  On VSTS, I get the following warnings/errors:

```
No package sources were found in the NuGet.config file at C:\a\1\s\development\.nuget\NuGet.config
setup.txt (0, 0)
setup.txt(0,0): Warning XA0101: @(Content) build action is not supported
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1820, 5)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): Warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Choosing "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" arbitrarily.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1820, 5)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): Warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLiteStore, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLiteStore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Choosing "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLiteStore, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" arbitrarily.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1820, 5)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): Warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLiteStore" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
development\ShoppingList.Mobile.Core\Services\ShoppingListService.cs (15, 17)
development\ShoppingList.Mobile.Core\Services\ShoppingListService.cs(15,17): Error CS0433: The type 'MobileServiceClient' exists in both 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
development\ShoppingList.Mobile.Core\Services\ShoppingListService.cs (16, 17)
development\ShoppingList.Mobile.Core\Services\ShoppingListService.cs(16,17): Error CS0433: The type 'IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>' exists in both 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

I have no idea where its pulling the reference to version 3.0.0.0 when building on VSTS.  Please help and thanks.

**Update**
In order to isolate where the problem is coming from, I added reference aliases to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLLiteStore references like this:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.3.1.0\lib\portable-win+net45+wp8+wpa81+monotouch+monoandroid\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
    <Aliases>core</Aliases>
</Reference>
```

and in code:

```
extern alias core;

using core.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using core.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;
using core.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;
```

This move has eliminated the above mentioned errors but a new one popped up:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets (1404, 2)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1404,2): Error : Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute()
```

That looks to me like package restore might not have worked correctly for this NuGet.  Will try to follow the steps from this article to see if I can correct package restore: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#msbuild-integrated-restore.

Comment: How do you create Xamarin.Android project (tool and steps)? Are there elements related to nugget in project file? (e.g. <import Project=”$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />)) If so, migrating to automatic restore (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#msbuild-integrated-restore) and add NuGet Installer build step to restore packages. What’re build steps of your build definition?

Comment: I believe the project was created as a Xamarin Native Blank App which creates projects for Android, iOS and UWP as well as an PCL.  I had some problems with the PCL (I played with the profile, etc.) so at some point in time, I have removed and re-created the PCL.  Its currently Profile111.  I am using VS2015.

Comment: @starain-MSFT My project has the following NuGet related section:  An empty <NuGetPackageImportStamp> under property group and hints to packages folder under <ItemGroup><Reference> section.  Note that packages are not added to VSTS.  I do have a .nuget folder which contains NuGet.config which contains only one section: <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />.  VSTS has NuGet restore added and that steps seems to complete fine.

Comment: @starain-MSFT Looking at the referenced article, I may not have all the steps down - I followed:  https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control#omitting-packages-with-team-foundation-version-control and  https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore#migrating-to-automatic-restore to enable automatic restore. My build definition is pretty vanilla: <br/> <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />

Comment: I am not clearly your comments, what's the result after migrating to automated restore? Can you build it on your machine manually? Do you add Nuget Restore step to build definition?

Comment: Which template you used? Provide the detail steps to create project.